Question about inequality of moments
Hope you are doing well. I am trying to solve whether the following expression is positive or negative:
$$\Xi_{i} = Var\left(\frac{1}{1-\theta_{i}}\right)\mathbb{E}\left[1-2\theta_{i}\right] + Cov\left(\left(\frac{1}{1-\theta_{i}}\right)^{2},1-2\theta_{i}\right)$$
where $\theta_{i}$ is a random variable with an arbitrary distribution, the only restriction is that $1-2\theta_{i}\geq 0$ for all realizations of $\theta_{i}$. I tried doing algebra but did not come to anything conclusive. I turned to a numerical exploration for the case of $\theta_{i}\sim \mathbb{U}\left[\mu-\sigma,\mu+\sigma\right]$. Below I plot for different values of $\mu$, and I vary $\sigma$ but making sure $\mu+\sigma<\frac{1}{2}$.

This makes me think $\Xi_{i}<0$ for any distribution, but I am not sure. Can you help me come up with a formal proof? Or at least give me a hint.
Thank you so much!

For more clarity, let's drop the subscript ($\theta_i$ and $\Xi_i$ will be written $\theta$ and $\Xi$). Plus, let's introduce:
$$X = \frac{1}{1-\theta} \quad \text{and}\quad Y = 1-2\theta$$
We can rewrite:
$$\Xi = \mathbb{Var}(X)\mathbb{E}[Y] + \mathbb{Cov}(X^2, Y)$$
We know that $\mathbb{Cov}(X^2, Y) = \mathbb{E}[X^2Y]-\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ so
$$\Xi = \mathbb{Var}(X)\mathbb{E}[Y] + \mathbb{E}[X^2Y] - \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[X^2Y] + \mathbb{E}[Y]\Big(\mathbb{Var}(X) - \mathbb{E}[X^2]\Big)$$
But $\mathbb{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$ and therefore $\Xi =\mathbb{E}[X^2Y] - \mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[X]^2$.
To further simplify $\Xi$, let's note that $Y= 1-2\theta = 1 - 2\cdot (1- 1/X) = -1+2/X$, so $$\Xi = \mathbb{E}[-X^2+2X] - \mathbb{E}\left[-1 + \frac{2}{X}\right]\mathbb{E}[X]^2 = -\mathbb{E}[X^2] + 2 \mathbb{E}[X]+ \mathbb{E}[X]^2-2\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]\mathbb{E}[X]^2$$
Because $\theta \leq \frac{1}{2}$, it means that $X> 0$, so by Jensen inequality $\mathbb{E}[1/X] \geq 1/\mathbb{E}[X]$ thus $\mathbb{E}[1/X]\mathbb{E}[X]^2 \geq \mathbb{E}[X]$.
Finally:
$$\Xi = - \left(\underbrace{\mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2}_{=\mathbb{Var}(X)\geq 0}\right) - 2 \left(\underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]\mathbb{E}[X]^2 - \mathbb{E}[X]}_{\geq 0}\right)\leq 0$$

Thank you so much!!!
